# WordPress htaccess issue with www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress website that is set to direct to www by default. Everything works perfectly, however I have a few sections that are custom coded, to go to "profile" pages of local services, accommodation etc. this works fine in development however on the live server when you access the link via www.example.com/services/example-here/ it redirects to example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-here/custom/services.php?slug=example-here

I've been told by my webhost that it is WordPRess that is causing the issue, however everything says www.example.com/ (siteurl etc.)

Here is the code in the htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^.*services/(.*)/$ /wp-content/themes/theme-here/custom/services.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^.*accommodation/(.*)/$ /wp-content/themes/theme-here/custom/accommodation.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas I've checked all my settings, Could it be a host issue inside of apache conf to do with mod re-write? I also might add that the code works perfectly without the www's added but my client requires the www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a `www` forcing rule on top of this .htaccess just below `RewriteBase /` line:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
   ```
2. Make sure in your `permalink` settings of WP you have blog address with `www`

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. Exact same thing is happening. What would cause it to ignore htaccess mod_rewrite rules (only some)

Comment: Open firebug and load the same page. See what you get in Net tab there.

Comment: `GET /services/garden-city-cabs/
 
302 Found
 
toowoombaconferences.com.au
 
389 B
 
103.9.170.219:80
 
 
77ms
 
GET services.php?slug=garden-city-cabs
 
301 Moved Permanently
 
toowoombaconferences.com.au
 
413 B
 
103.9.170.219:80`

Comment: So the last 301 is forcing a domain without `www` in URL. have you tried different browsers to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Hi,I managed to fix it myself, don't know what it was.. I just changed the virtual directory to a different name and then back again and it worked... could be a WordPress issue.

Comment: Hmm most likely web server needed a bounce, glad that it worked out.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve/understand your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.